# LDAP_BIND (Invalid DN) Webmin User And Group DB (Docker)

Tags: ldap, webmin

I have some issues with my Webmin when i try to bind it to the User and Group DB to allow LDAP users enter on webmin i have this issue

```
Failed to login to LDAP server as admin : invalid DN
```

So i when i check my logs on openldap this is what i have

```
ber_dump: buf=0x7f33f4002400 ptr=0x7f33f4002400 end=0x7f33f4002419 len=25
  0000:  02 01 01 60 14 02 01 03  04 05 61 64 6d 69 6e 80   ...`......admin.
  0010:  08 4e 44 67 35 47 36 44  46                        .password
ber_dump: buf=0x7f33f4002400 ptr=0x7f33f4002403 end=0x7f33f4002419 len=22
  0000:  60 14 02 01 03 04 05 61  64 6d 69 6e 80 08 4e 44   `......admin....
  0010:  67 35 47 36 44 46                                  password
ber_dump: buf=0x7f33f4002400 ptr=0x7f33f400240f end=0x7f33f4002419 len=10
  0000:  00 08 4e 44 67 35 47 36  44 46                     ..password
5ebde922 conn=1001 op=0 do_bind: invalid dn (admin)
  0000:  30 16 02 01 01 61 11 0a  01 22 04 00 04 0a 69 6e   0....a..."....in
  0010:  76 61 6c 69 64 20 44 4e                            valid DN
```

Btw, with phpadmin it works great no issues,

so i will post the log here in debug 256

```
5ebdea13 conn=1000 op=0 do_bind: invalid dn (admin)
5ebdea13 conn=1000 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=34 text=invalid DN
5ebdea14 conn=1000 fd=12 closed (connection lost)


Thanks,

Info 
OS:Ubuntu 18.04
Openldap under docker.
Webmin under docker
```

Comment: I think the username is probably cn=admin,dc=balckdragon,dc=tv (or maybe just cn=admin)

Comment: Is its right thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, what was wrong. I was trying to bind with:

```
dc=example, dc=com
```

Instead of:

```
cn=Administrator, dc=example, dc=com
```